# Which IPhone control would be better?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uibutton

I have a situation in which user can single tap a control, which show random images, to peek under it, double tap to mark it, or drag it to a box where it snaps to the box if more than half of its body is inside box.

I was using UIbuttons (with background image) before and have done the single/double tap thing for them, how to do the drag and snap to a box based on the cross-section of covered area by box?

What if i use uiimage? i know dragging a uiimage object is possible, is double/single tap is also possible for uiimage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with UIImageView - you can implement the various touch methods just as easily on any UIView descendant, which includes UIImageView.

Comment: Agreed. I'd probably use the UIImageView.